# python add copy element of the list to list

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x

Could anyone help to improve my code?
So, firstly. I've a list with one element. 
I need to make a new list that consists of duplicates of the element of the given list num times. However, some values for cloned elements such as id, name, fullname, login...must be different.

I'm writing code like this:

```
num = 5
list =  list1
list1 = [copy.deepcopy(x) for item in list for x in repeat(item, num)]
for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    list1[i]['account']['id'] = randint(2,10)
    list1[i]['account']['name'] = 'name' + randint(2,10)
    list1[i]['account']['FullName'] = 'statusName' + randint(2,10)
    list1[i]['account']['login'] = 'login'  + randint(2,10)
    list1[i]['account']['contract']['id']= randint(2,10)
```

I wonder Is there any way to make it more efficient? I have the same task yet with much bigger list and it seems too many code lines for this...

thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like you have a list of dictionaries ? in which case you might want to think about using classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is to find the slowest part of the code and focus on that. I recommend using the `cProfile` module, like this, and it will tell you which part of your code is the slowest:

```
import copy
import cProfile

def main():
    # ...your earlier code goes here
    num = 5
    list =  list1
    list1 = [copy.deepcopy(x) for item in list for x in repeat(item, num)]
    for i, val in enumerate(list1):
        list1[i]['account']['id'] = randint(2,10)
        list1[i]['account']['name'] = 'name' + randint(2,10)
        list1[i]['account']['FullName'] = 'statusName' + randint(2,10)
        list1[i]['account']['login'] = 'login'  + randint(2,10)
        list1[i]['account']['contract']['id']= randint(2,10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cProfile.run("main()", sort="cumulative")
```